# Laravel phpunit does not run any test

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

I cannot get any test to run, there are also no errors.

I downloaded `phpunit` and moved it to `/usr/local/bin`.

I did not do any config change on my fresh laravel installation.

`cd` to my laravel root directory. `phpunit --version` gives `PHPUnit 4.0.12`

There is an laravel example test located at `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/survey-backend/app/tests/ExampleTest.php`.

Now, running tests with: `phpunit` outputs only:

`Configuration read from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/survey-backend/phpunit.xml`

Why is the test not being executed?

Comment: It doesn't hang on that does it? You can try running it with `phpunit --debug` to see if it picks up the test. Only other thing worth checking is that you've run `composer update` and the autoload files have been generated correctly.

Comment: If no tests were found it should also output "no tests ran". You should grep your code for `die()` or `exit()`, and check your PHP CLI log for out of memory errors.

Comment: Thanks. No it does not hang. I have not changed anything with `composer`. Is there any config needed? I will run `update` and `debug` later. There is no other test file but the example test file by laravel.

Comment: Is it necessary to use or config `composer`? I only installed phpunit and nothing more.

Comment: Running `phpunit --debug` gives `Configuration read from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/survey-backend/phpunit.xml


Starting test 'ExampleTest::testBasicExample'.`. But there is no result.

Comment: Ok I am sorry. I found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This failed all the time due to a fatal error because I included classes in the `start.php` that were available when using via `/public` but were missing when calling from `phpunit`. I have now added them to `composer.json` and everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to note that I also had this issue and it ended up being that I used **private** rather than **protected** when adding a `tearDown()` method to the TestCase class.